# Is there a way to make my app activity go back to foreground after users inactivity?

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, service

As a Unity3D developer, I've created an application and exported it to Android Studio. My client is asking me to make this app go back to foreground after 10 seconds of user's inactivity (in case the user opens another app). I've tried to create a service that is started on the OnPause function of my UnityPlayerActivity. Then the service would detect the user's inactivity and launch my app again (putting it back to foreground). First I've only tried to use  Time.Schedule to launch my app after 10 seconds no matter what, but everytime the application is paused (goes to background), it starts the service and then it crashes. The question is: is there a simple way to do this? I'm not an Android Java Developer (only know the basics) and I'm struggling with this part .

I'm trying to create this Service and then I try to start it from the onPause() function in my activity. When I pause the app on my phone the app crashes. Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right way and, please, help me?

```
public class ReturnToForeground extends Service {
    public ReturnToForeground() {
    }

    // constant
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // 10 seconds

    // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // timer handling
    private Timer mTimer = null;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // cancel if already existed
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // do action
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To clearfy you are asking for a way to force the user back into your app when he leaves the app for ten seconds and you want to do this with unity ?

Comment: Hi. Not exactly. I want to "force" the user back into my app if he's not using the phone for ten seconds. I know I will have to do this using a service, but I don't want to do this with Unity, I'm trying to use Android Studio (despite the fact I'm not a Java developer). I won't put this app on the play store, of course, it's just for my client, he's the only person who will use this. I want to know how to make this service run properly without crashing the app.

Comment: `My client is asking me to make this app go back to foreground after 10 seconds of user's inactivity (in case the user opens another app` this sounds like either a very nasty spam which I as user would not like to support here ... or is an attempt of creating a custom phone locker? Both has not much todo with Unity in the first place ..

Comment: @derHugo ahahahaha no, it's not a spam. My app has an Augmented Reality Experience which will be running in some points of sale. It's more like a custom phone locker, as you said. The app keeps running a video, when the user grabs the phone it starts the AR Experience, if the user stops using the phone, it gets back to the video, but if the user opens another app and then stops using the phone, my app is brought back to foreground after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Make a timer for when the app is in the onPause(), when the timer reaches 10 seconds you should pass an intent which will make your app active again (let's say taking the user back to the main view). You can save the current data of your app in something like shared preffs, so that information wont be lost in most situations.

In many cases this problem appears when a resource which you are trying to reload is not active anymore inside the application.

From the info you have shared it seems like you are not starting the service correctly. It would be nice if you can add a crash log so that we can debug it and see where is the problem.

Comment: Oh, so the OnPause() function keeps running while the app is in background? I thought it was only called once. So I put this timer in the onPause() function itself and not inside the service code?

Comment: Actually no, you are right, but you can have a workaround where you have a threat spawned for this activity, the moment its on pause, which thread will be counting the seconds, and when its done you will transition to your app, and kill the thread :) sorry for my mistake in the answer above

Comment: hahahaha no problem!! How can I start this thread? I was trying to create a service and my activity started it from the onPause() function. My service had a Timer.Schedule that within 10 seconds should've started the UnityPlayerActivity (my app). But - I don't know why - this makes the application crash.

Comment: Start it as you would normally create a thread. 
Kill it like this 
protected void onPause() {
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
     super.onPause();
}

Comment: The thread keeps running even if the app is in Background? Ok, I'll try this